# From a 'value' to a 'lemma'

Tags: isabelle

I have a rather large term `foo`. When I type

```
value "foo"
```

then Isabelle evaluates `foo` to a value, say `foo_value`. I would now like to prove the following lemma.

```
lemma "foo = foo_value"
```

What proof method should I use? I tried `try`, but that timed out. I guess I could proceed manually by unfolding the various definitions that occur in `foo`, but surely I should be able to tap into whatever mechanism the `value` command is using, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three proof methods that correspond to the different evaluation mechanisms of `value`:

- `eval` uses the code generator; it corresponds to `value [code]`. The proof succeeds if the generated ML code evaluates to `True`.
- `normalization` compiles the statement to a symbolic normalisation engine in ML. It mimicks `value [nbe]`.
- `code_simp` uses Isabelle's simplifier as an evaluator. It corresponds to `value [simp]`.

The [tutorial on code generation](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2013-2/doc/codegen.pdf) describes these proof methods in more detail. `eval` and `normalization` act like oracles, i.e., they bypass Isabelle's kernel whereas every evaluation step of `code_simp` goes through the kernel. Usually, `eval` is faster than `normalization` and `normalization` is faster than `code_simp`.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, that's very interesting and helpful. I'm curious: if the first two methods bypass the kernel, can one say that the lemma has been properly proved? Would I be allowed, for instance, to submit a theory containing `by eval` to the Archive of Formal Proofs?

Comment: If you use one of the first two methods, then you trust that the code generator setup is sound. It should not be a problem to submit `by eval` proofs to the AFP, there are already a couple of them in there. In fact, all the reflective proof methods rely on evaluation, too. An example is the `regexp` method in the AFP entry Regular Sets and Expressions http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/Regular-Sets.shtml.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it works in all cases, but you could try:

```
lemma "foo = foo_value"
  by eval
```

In many cases, `by simp` should also work and I guess `eval` is kind of an oracle (in the sense that it is not fully verified by the kernel; please somebody correct me if I am wrong).