# Isabelle verbose evaluation steps

Tags: isabelle

Is there some way to see what the `value` command does under the hood?
Maybe there exists something like `using [[simp_trace]]` but for `value`

```
value  using [[simp_trace]] "2+4::nat"
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a Simplifier tracing feature which works for an individual execution of `value`, but at least you can emulate it by using `declare [[simp_trace]]` before your `value` command to enable tracing and `declare [[simp_trace=false]]` afterwards to disable tracing.

Comment: value can use several strategies (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837564/from-a-value-to-a-lemma). If you are using the default strategy, you generate the SML code and see what happens there.